# Should filename extension be part of the filename?

Tags: windows, filenames

See this picture, screenshotted from my Windows explorer. Notice both are considered JS files, because that's the type I chose when I saved them. But for one, I actually called it `test.js` and for the other, just `test`. I can't figure out which of these is right.

Does the first one have an incomplete name, or does the second one have a redundant *.js* in its name, making its full name `test.js.js`?

Is one of these wrong, and likely to cause problems when my application is loading up and goes looking for a file named `test.js`? Does this vary on other operating systems?

[image]

Comment: What does `dir` in a `cmd` shell display?

Comment: As InterLinked says, "Hide file extensions for known filetypes" is probably enabled. And one of the files has double-extension, "test.js.js".

Answer (score 1):

This depends. In your view options, do you have 'Hide file extensions for known filetypes' checked? If so, you should NOT see thr file extension. If it is checked, then you SHOULD see the file extension.

Now, there isn't any harm done by including the extension in the filename, it will just confuse things up. Based on the screenshot you have provided, I would guess that your box is checked, which is the default in Windows.